# how to remove "Group" dropdown feild in order create form in backend in magento 2

Tags: backend, magento2.3.3, admin-order-create, remove

I need to remove the "Group" dropdown field in order to create a form in the backend ?

Can anyone guide me to remove this field in magento2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the part you're looking for is located in the **`sales_order_create_index.xml`** file in the layout folder of the backend in **`module-sales`** in a vendor folder.

If you want to completely remove Group dropdown and email field then you need to modify ( **DO NOT directly modify the vendor file, use overriding mechanism by module or theme** ):

```
ProjectDirectory/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml
```

and then there you need to remove the block:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form/account.phtml" name="form_account"/>
```

---

**If you want to only remove the Group dropdown, follow below steps:**

Create or use your existing module whichever you prefer.

1. **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" />
    </config>
   ```
2. **Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Account.php**

   ```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Account extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account
    {
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $customerForm */
            $customerForm = $this->_metadataFormFactory->create('customer', 'adminhtml_checkout');

            // prepare customer attributes to show
            $attributes = [];

            // add system required attributes
            foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
                if( $attribute->getAttributeCode() != 'group_id' ) { //Line added
                    if ($attribute->isRequired()) {
                        $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($this->getQuote()->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
                unset($attributes['group_id']);
            }

            // add user defined attributes
            foreach ($customerForm->getUserAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
            }

            $fieldset = $this->_form->addFieldset('main', []);

            $this->_addAttributesToForm($attributes, $fieldset);

            $this->_form->addFieldNameSuffix('order[account]');
            $this->_form->setValues($this->extractValuesFromAttributes($attributes));

            return $this;
        }
        private function extractValuesFromAttributes(array $attributes): array
        {
            $formValues = $this->getFormValues();
            foreach ($attributes as $code => $attribute) {
                $defaultValue = $attribute->getDefaultValue();
                if (isset($defaultValue) && !isset($formValues[$code])) {
                    $formValues[$code] = $defaultValue;
                }
            }

            return $formValues;
        }
    }
   ```

[image]

**Explanation**: What we've done here is, it is automatically binding the attributes so if you remove the complete code it'll also remove email field. So, in order to remove only Group down we have to modify _prepareForm function and added a condition in foreach `if( $attribute->getAttributeCode() != 'group_id' )`, so it'll skip Group attribute. and since extractValuesFromAttributes function is a private function, we also need it to put it in our preference file as we cannot call private method in _prepareForm from extending class.

Comment: Its not working for me any idea

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to use General and you are pretty certain that your users don't do bad things the easiest way is just to hide it via CSS.

If you want to "properly" remove it you have to

A) `remove it from the ui_component`

B) `extend the functionality to auto set the group as it as a required value.`

This will override and/or extend a lot of core features which will be harder to maintain, therefore i highly suggest the css approach.